# Ocaml error message Error: Parse error: "in" expected after [binding] (in [expr])

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a function that counts the number of divisors in n up to m divisors (where current is the current divisor, and count is the total number of divisors so far)

I get the error Error: Parse error: "in" expected after [binding] (in [expr]) for the last line of code, but I don't really see how "in" could be the last line. What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
    (* Counts the number of divisors*)
    let rec count_divisors (n: int) (m: int) (current: int) (count: int): int =
       if count > m || current > n then count
       else  if (n mod current) = 0 then count_divisors n m (current+1) (count+1)
       else (count_divisors n m (current+1) count);;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use this function within another function (since it has so many parameters where I would expect only one single parameter -- the number whose divisors you want to compute), right?

If so, try changing your code to the following:

```
let num_divisors n =
    let rec count_divisors (n: int) (m: int) (current: int) (count: int): int =
           if count > m || current > n then count
           else  if (n mod current) = 0 then count_divisors n m (current+1) (count+1)
           else (count_divisors n m (current+1) count)
    in count_divisors n n 1 0;;
```